# Calculating millisecond and avoiding float numbers

Tags: algorithms

I have a variable which increases/decreases from `0` to `255` every `(X) millisecond`. so:

```
(X) x 255 = time in millisecond / 60000 = minute
```

`(X) millisecond` is a variable which increases only by it self, for example after each button press:

```
(X) + (X) x 255 = time in millisecond / 60000 = minute
(X) + (X) + (X) x 255 = time in millisecond / 60000 = minute
etc
```

What number should we use in (X) so every time it increases i get `+1` minute in output.
I want an integer number not a float.

*The language is C++ if it helps in anyway...*

Comment: This question does not seem to be about computer science concepts, but either about cross-multiplication or programming (hard to tell).

Comment: newbie, please remember to [be nice](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Disagreement with your views or upholding community policies are not rudeness. Deep breaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to find a value for $X$ in milliseconds so that $X  \times 255$ is equal to $60000$ milliseconds which is one minute. And you want $X$ to be an integer.

Well, $60000 = 235 \times 255 + 75$. So you can either use $X=235$ milliseconds, in which case $X \times 255$ is 75 milliseconds less than one minute. Or you can use $X=236$ milliseconds, in which case $X \times 255$ is $180$ milliseconds more than one minute. But you cannot find an integer value for $X$ which makes $X \times 255$ exactly $60000$.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @DavidRicherbyI imagine if and when there is consensus that the question should not be answered then it will be put on hold.

Comment: Yes, it will be put on hold. But please don't answer off-topic questions. Or, if you believe that the question is on-topic, you should probably edit your answer to highlight the relevant computer science concepts involved.

Comment: gandalf61, please consider that answering offtopic or bad questions will encourage more of the same.